# Getting other language after encoding along with errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

My aim is to build a stemmer in Python for text like this

> भारत का इतिहास काफी समृद्ध एवं विस्तृत है।अपने क्षेत्र में खास उपलब्धियां हासिल करने वाली कुछ महिलाओं का उदाहरण देकर हम महिलाओं की उन्नती को दर्शाते है। पर अगर आप ध्यान दे तो कुछ अदभुत करने वाली महिलाएं तो हर काल में रही है। सीता से लेकर द्रौपदी, रज़िया सुल्तान से लेकर रानी दुर्गावति, रानी लक्ष्मीबाई से लेकर इंदिरा गांधी एवं किरण बेदी एवं सानिया मिर्ज़ा। परन्तु महिलाओं की स्थिति में कितना परिवर्तन आया? और आम महिलाओं ने परिवर्तन को किस तरह से देखा?
>   7065534

It should output something like this without stems:

> भारत का इतिहास काफी समृद्ध एवं विस्तृत है।अपने क्षेत्र में खास उपलब्धि हासिल करने वाली कुछ महिला का उदाहरण देकर हम महिला की उन्नती को दर्शाते है। पर अगर आप ध्यान दे तो कुछ अदभुत करने वाली महिला तो हर काल में रही है। सीता से लेकर द्रौपदी, रज़िया सुल्तान से लेकर रानी दुर्गावति, रानी लक्ष्मीबाई से लेकर इंदिरा गांधी एवं किरण बेदी एवं सानिया मिर्ज़ा। परन्तु महिला की स्थिति में कितना परिवर्तन आया? और आम महिला ने परिवर्तन को किस तरह से देखा? 7065534

But I get output as

> ï » ¿ à ¤ ­ à ¤ ¾ à ¤ ° à ¤ ¤   à ¤ • à ¤ ¾   à ¤ ‡ à ¤ ¤ à ¤ ¿ à ¤......like this

That is anything inside the dictionary (code) should be striped after working through algorithm I am getting an error to encode or decode being a beginner it is hard to resolve

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import re
separators = [u"।", u",", u"."]
dat=open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\text1.txt",'r').read()
print dat
text=dat.decode("utf-8")
out=[]

suffx = {
    1:  ["ो", "े", "ू", "ु", "ी", "ि", "ा"],
    2:  ["कर", "ाओ", "िए", "ाई", "ाए", "ने", "नी", "ना", "ते", "ीं", "ती", "ता", "ाँ", "ां", "ों", "ें"],
    3:  ["ाकर", "ाइए", "ाईं", "ाया", "ेगी", "ेगा", "ोगी", "ोगे", "ाने", "ाना", "ाते", "ाती", "ाता", "तीं", "ाओं", "ाएं", "ुओं", "ुएं", "ुआं"],
    4:  ["ाएगी", "ाएगा", "ाओगी", "ाओगे", "एंगी", "ेंगी", "एंगे", "ेंगे", "ूंगी", "ूंगा", "ातीं", "नाओं", "नाएं", "ताओं", "ताएं", "ियाँ", "ियों", "ियां"],
    5:  ["ाएंगी", "ाएंगे", "ाऊंगी", "ाऊंगा", "ाइयाँ", "ाइयों", "ाइयां","िया","ीया","वाला","ेवाला","ाऊ","ाका","ालू","ेरा","ेया","हारा","ाक","ाड़ी","क","न","ावा"],
    6:  ["ंत","ाई","ावट","ाहट","या","कर","ना","कार","ेरा","वाला","ार","ची","पन","ीमा","िमा","पा","ाल","जा","िक","िया","टी","टा","ड़ी","ड़ा","हरा","सा","था","िय","ीय","ीला","िला","लु","वंत","वान","ौती"],
}
j=1;
for l in 1,2,3,4,5,6:
        for j in suffx[l]:
            #print j.decode("utf-8")
            print j

import string
#print type( r3_bad)
#print type(r3_bad[1])
space=[]
suffix=[]
i=0;


def stemmed_word(word):

    for k in 1,2,3,4,5,6:
        j=1;
        for j in suffx[k]:
            if(word.endswith(j)):
                return(word[:-j])
    return word

for word in dat :
    removed=""
    removed=stemmed_word(word)
    #i+=1
    out.append(removed)


print out 
result = u' '.join(out)

result = result.encode('utf-8')

result=' '.join(out)
writ=open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\text5.txt",'w')

writ.write(result)
writ.close()

def remove3(str_re,re_bad):
    #to remove or replace the string having bad chars defined
    outrm=str_re.translate(string.maketrans("","", ), re_bad)
    print "function called:"+word
    return outrm;
```

Comment: python 2.7 doesn't get along too easily with unicode, you'll be better served upgrading to python 3

Comment: @JKirchartz how will that effect my code..?

Comment: @JKirchartz still there is no change!

Comment: I think I know what's wrong with your program, and I'll try to fix it. In future, please don't post messy code. You should post a [mcve] that focuses on your problem.

Comment: @PM2Ring please try solving it ! error is basically it is not able to convert the unicode back an dgives me messy output!!

Comment: As  JKirchartz said, Python3 is much better for working with Unicode. Also, Python 2 will reach its official End Of Life in 2020, so you should seriously think about migrating to Python 3. In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Please let me know if you need help understanding my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a repaired version of your code which runs correctly on both Python 2 and Python 3 (tested on Python 2.6.6 and Python 3.6.0).

You need to be careful not to mix Unicode with non-Unicode, especially in Python 2. So I converted your suffix table to use proper Unicode strings with the `u` prefix; that prefix isn't necessary in Python 3, since all text strings in Python 3 are Unicode (it has a separate `bytes` type for strings of bytes).

Also, when you write UTF-8 data to a file you **must** open the file in binary mode (and of course, the same applies when reading such files). It doesn't matter in Unix-like operating systems, but it's *essential* on Windows because Windows does "special" processing on text files that can mess up binary data.

This program uses `str.translate` to remove the unwanted separator characters. To make the code run correctly on both versions I constructed the translation table directly, rather than using `maketrans`. In Python 2, `maketrans` is a function in the `string` module, but it's a `str` method in Python 3, and there are subtle differences between the two versions. Fortunately `str.translate` still works the same way.

There was a bug in your `stemmed_word` function. `j` is a string, but in the last line you do `word[:-j]`, which doesn't make sense: you can't use a string as an index like that.

I got rid of your `remove3` function. I'm not sure what it's supposed to do, and the code you posted doesn't actually call it.

I've embedded the text directly as a Unicode string into the script itself, but you should be able to read it into the script from a file if you read it in binary mode as I mentioned earlier, and then call `.decode('utf-8')` on the bytes you read in.

Eg,

```
with open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\text1.txt", 'rb') as f:
    text = f.read().decode("utf-8")
```

Here's the code that removes the suffixes from all words in the text, after removing the separators.

```
from __future__ import print_function

# Make a translation table that deletes separators
separators = u"।,.?"
sep_table = dict((ord(s), None) for s in separators)

# A dictionary of suffixes to remove
suffx = {
    1:  [u"ो", u"े", u"ू", u"ु", u"ी", u"ि", u"ा"],
    2:  [u"कर", u"ाओ", u"िए", u"ाई", u"ाए", u"ने", u"नी", u"ना", u"ते",
    u"ीं", u"ती", u"ता", u"ाँ", u"ां", u"ों", u"ें"],
    3:  [u"ाकर", u"ाइए", u"ाईं", u"ाया", u"ेगी", u"ेगा", u"ोगी", u"ोगे",
    u"ाने", u"ाना", u"ाते", u"ाती", u"ाता", u"तीं", u"ाओं", u"ाएं", u"ुओं",
    u"ुएं", u"ुआं"],
    4:  [u"ाएगी", u"ाएगा", u"ाओगी", u"ाओगे", u"एंगी", u"ेंगी", u"एंगे",
    u"ेंगे", u"ूंगी", u"ूंगा", u"ातीं", u"नाओं", u"नाएं", u"ताओं", u"ताएं",
    u"ियाँ", u"ियों", u"ियां"],
    5:  [u"ाएंगी", u"ाएंगे", u"ाऊंगी", u"ाऊंगा", u"ाइयाँ", u"ाइयों",
    u"ाइयां", u"िया", u"ीया", u"वाला", u"ेवाला", u"ाऊ", u"ाका", u"ालू",
    u"ेरा", u"ेया", u"हारा", u"ाक", u"ाड़ी", u"क", u"न", u"ावा"],
    6:  [u"ंत", u"ाई", u"ावट", u"ाहट", u"या", u"कर", u"ना", u"कार", u"ेरा",
    u"वाला", u"ार", u"ची", u"पन", u"ीमा", u"िमा", u"पा", u"ाल", u"जा",
    u"िक", u"िया", u"टी", u"टा", u"ड़ी", u"ड़ा", u"हरा", u"सा", u"था",
    u"िय", u"ीय", u"ीला", u"िला", u"लु", u"वंत", u"वान", u"ौती"],
}

# Show the suffixes
#for k in range(1, 7):
    #print(k, ':', u" ".join(suffx[k]))

# The text to process
input_text = u"भारत का इतिहास काफी समृद्ध एवं विस्तृत है।अपने क्षेत्र में खास उपलब्धियां हासिल करने वाली कुछ महिलाओं का उदाहरण देकर हम महिलाओं की उन्नती को दर्शाते है। पर अगर आप ध्यान दे तो कुछ अदभुत करने वाली महिलाएं तो हर काल में रही है। सीता से लेकर द्रौपदी, रज़िया सुल्तान से लेकर रानी दुर्गावति, रानी लक्ष्मीबाई से लेकर इंदिरा गांधी एवं किरण बेदी एवं सानिया मिर्ज़ा। परन्तु महिलाओं की स्थिति में कितना परिवर्तन आया? और आम महिलाओं ने परिवर्तन को किस तरह से देखा?"

def stemmed_word(word):
    ''' Look for a suffix in a word, and if found, remove it '''
    for k in range(1, 7):
        for s in suffx[k]:
            if word.endswith(s):
                return(word[:-len(s)])
    return word

# Remove the separators from the text
text = input_text.translate(sep_table)

print("Original")
print(text)

# Split the text into a list of words
dat = text.split()

# Make a list of the stemmed words
out = []
for word in dat :
    removed = stemmed_word(word)
    out.append(removed)

#Add a newline to the end
out.append(u"\n")

# Join the words back into a single Unicode string
result = u" ".join(out)
print("Stemmed")
print(result)

# Save the result to disk, encoded as UTF-8
fname = "text_utf8.txt"
with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result.encode('utf-8'))
```

**output**

```
Original
भारत का इतिहास काफी समृद्ध एवं विस्तृत हैअपने क्षेत्र में खास उपलब्धियां हासिल करने वाली कुछ महिलाओं का उदाहरण देकर हम महिलाओं की उन्नती को दर्शाते है पर अगर आप ध्यान दे तो कुछ अदभुत करने वाली महिलाएं तो हर काल में रही है सीता से लेकर द्रौपदी रज़िया सुल्तान से लेकर रानी दुर्गावति रानी लक्ष्मीबाई से लेकर इंदिरा गांधी एवं किरण बेदी एवं सानिया मिर्ज़ा परन्तु महिलाओं की स्थिति में कितना परिवर्तन आया और आम महिलाओं ने परिवर्तन को किस तरह से देखा
Stemmed
भारत क इतिहास काफ समृद्ध एवं विस्तृत हैअपन क्षेत्र म खास उपलब्धिय हासिल करन वाल कुछ महिल क उदाहरण दे हम महिल क उन्नत क दर्शात है पर अगर आप ध्या द त कुछ अदभुत करन वाल महिल त हर क म रह है सीत स ले द्रौपद रज़िय सुल्ता स ले रान दुर्गावत रान लक्ष्मीब स ले इंदिर गांध एवं किरण बेद एवं सानिय मिर्ज़ परन्त महिल क स्थित म कितन परिवर्त आय और आम महिल न परिवर्त क किस तरह स देख
```

The contents of "text_utf8.txt" should look identical to the Stemmed output above if you tell your editor to open it with UTF-8 encoding.